How can I read a parquet file that is snappy compressed using C++ apache-arrow package?
I used the following codes to read a parquet file successfully if "b.parquet" had not been compressed.
#include <iostream>
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/io/api.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/reader.h>
#include <arrow/util/logging.h>
#include <arrow/ipc/api.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/reader.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/writer.h>


arrow::Status RunMain() {

    auto pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> file;
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(file, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open("b.parquet"));

    std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> reader;
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::OpenFile(file, arrow::default_memory_pool(), &reader));

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> parquet_table;
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(reader->ReadTable(&parquet_table));
 
    std::cout << "Table Data:\n";
    std::cout << parquet_table->ToString() << std::endl;

    return arrow::Status::OK();
}

int main() {
    arrow::Status st = RunMain();
    if (!st.ok()) {
        std::cerr << st << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

However, when I replaced "b.parquet" into a compressed one. The console would display garbled characters like:
By the way, "b.parquet" was actually formed by following Python codes. And the function "pandas.dataframe.to_parquet" seems using snappy compression by default.
b = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[9,10,11,101]])
b.to_parquet('b.parquet')

If I change the above python code a little, like:
b = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[9,10,11,101]])
b.to_parquet('b.parquet', compression=None)

Then, the C++ code will work.
So, my question is : If I have a lot of parquet files that have been already compressed, how can I read them?

You should add a try/catch block around the parquet code and log the exception being thrown.  I would guess the issue is you are linked against a version of arrow that doesn't have snappy compression libraries linked in.
